# dataTimeDay keeps changing once if statement runs

Tags: javascript, if-statement, debugging

```
function weatherImageMaker(){
console.log(dataTimeDay+" before if");
if(dataTimeDay="//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/"+dataIconCode+".png"){
    let dataNightImageSrc;
    dataNightImageSrc="images/icons/weather/64x64/night/"+dataIconCode+".png";
    weatherImage.src=dataNightImageSrc;
    weatherMenuContainer.style.backgroundImage="url(images/backgrounds/nightsky.jpg)";
}else{
    let dataDayImageSrc;
    dataDayImageSrc="images/icons/weather/64x64/day/"+dataIconCode+".png";
    weatherImage.src=dataDayImageSrc;
    weatherMenuContainer.style.backgroundImage="url(images/backgrounds/wp7399540.webp)";
};
console.log(dataTimeDay+" after if");
```

};

Before the if statement the console tells me that dataDayTime=//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/122.png, but then the if statement passes even though the condition isnt met. Then when the function is completed dayTimeData=//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/122.png

Comment: Look at your IF statement. You're using a single `=` which is _setting_ (not evaluating) the variable

Comment: I love you so much